# A remark on the convergence of $f(rx,ry)$ (periodic in the second variable) as $r \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be periodic in the second variable.

Suppose  $f(rx,ry)$ converges, as $r\to \infty$, to a function $\tilde{f}$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R}$.

Does $\tilde{f}$ depend only on $y$? Or is $\tilde{f}$ constant?

Comment: @copper.hat A function. And I want to prove that it only depends on $y$.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, it is.